# error installing/running Meteor with MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, meteor, meteorite

I have installed Meteorite on my mac, and am trying to run the test program provided as a mysql project.  When I use the command 'mrt', I get:

Stand back while Meteorite does its thing

Done installing smart packages

Ok, everything's ready. Here comes Meteor!

[[[[[ /Users/lfrey/Desktop/Thesis/test-meteor-sql ]]]]]

=> Errors prevented startup:

While building the application:
node_modules/meteor/app/lib/unsupported.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets  for you)
node_modules/meteor/app/meteor/meteor.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.

I have tried re-installing nom, meteor, meteorite, and mysql in various combinations and have not been able to eliminate the error. If I remove the  command, then I get an error about invalid HTML syntax.

Comment: Googling the 'Can't set DOCTYPE here' error with meteor has a bunch of people saying 'rm -rf node_modules' worked for them. If node_modules is in fact in your app's root directory that does seem like a problem

Answer (score 1):

Your app might not be created properly. You have a `node_modules` directory in your application which you might have added with `npm install`.

Meteor does not install modules with `npm install` manually, it doesn't work because it parses files in the `node_moules` directory as part of your meteor app (in the wrong way - not as an npm module).

You have to make sure the package you use uses `Npm.depends` in your package's `package.js`. The standard Meteor-SQL package already does this for you so you don't have to worry about it.

Which SQL package did you use? As far as I can see none of them install anything with `npm install` nor do they have instructions to.

The simple fix to get your app working is to remove the modules you installed by deleting the node_modules directory in your app.